# MPMediaQuery playlistQuery with iCloud filter predicate returning incorrect number of items in a collection

Tags: ios, mpmediaquery

I've successfully filtered out all items in the iCloud for every part of my app except the playlists. Upon showing the list of playlists, there is a sub-header inside each cell which reads the number of tracks in that playlist. The problem is that the number of items in a collection is incorrect (despite the total number of items of the query itself being correct).

Code:

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:0] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo];

MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
[query addFilterPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"(iCloud) Total number of items in query: %d",query.items.count);

int i=1;

for (MPMediaItemCollection *collection in query.collections) {
    NSLog(@"(iCloud) Number of items in playlist %d: %d",i,collection.items.count);
    i++;
}


MPMediaQuery *query2 = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];

NSLog(@"(All) Total number of items in query: %d",query2.items.count);

i=0;

for (MPMediaItemCollection *collection in query2.collections) {
    NSLog(@"(All) Number of items in playlist %d: %d",i,collection.items.count);
    i++;
}
```

Log:

```
2013-02-16 20:46:08.904 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Total number of items in query: 99
2013-02-16 20:46:08.918 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 1: 5
2013-02-16 20:46:08.924 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 2: 1
2013-02-16 20:46:08.930 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 3: 19
2013-02-16 20:46:08.950 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 4: 312
2013-02-16 20:46:08.956 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 5: 5
2013-02-16 20:46:08.963 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 6: 44
2013-02-16 20:46:09.003 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 7: 16
2013-02-16 20:46:09.009 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 8: 31
2013-02-16 20:46:09.015 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 9: 90
2013-02-16 20:46:09.023 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 10: 42
2013-02-16 20:46:09.069 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 11: 296
2013-02-16 20:46:09.074 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 12: 2
2013-02-16 20:46:09.134 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 13: 25
2013-02-16 20:46:09.139 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 14: 4
2013-02-16 20:46:09.143 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 15: 1
2013-02-16 20:46:09.147 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 16: 3
2013-02-16 20:46:09.153 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 17: 19
2013-02-16 20:46:09.158 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 18: 5
2013-02-16 20:46:09.162 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 19: 7
2013-02-16 20:46:09.167 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 20: 14
2013-02-16 20:46:09.177 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 21: 247
2013-02-16 20:46:09.182 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 22: 12
2013-02-16 20:46:09.186 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 23: 2
2013-02-16 20:46:09.191 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 24: 5
2013-02-16 20:46:09.195 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 25: 2
2013-02-16 20:46:09.199 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 26: 5
2013-02-16 20:46:09.213 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 27: 239
2013-02-16 20:46:09.218 MyApp[62357:907] (iCloud) Number of items in playlist 28: 11
2013-02-16 20:46:09.265 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Total number of items in query: 3788
2013-02-16 20:46:09.269 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 0: 5
2013-02-16 20:46:09.270 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 1: 1
2013-02-16 20:46:09.271 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 2: 19
2013-02-16 20:46:09.272 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 3: 312
2013-02-16 20:46:09.272 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 4: 5
2013-02-16 20:46:09.273 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 5: 44
2013-02-16 20:46:09.274 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 6: 16
2013-02-16 20:46:09.275 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 7: 31
2013-02-16 20:46:09.275 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 8: 90
2013-02-16 20:46:09.276 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 9: 42
2013-02-16 20:46:09.277 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 10: 296
2013-02-16 20:46:09.277 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 11: 2
2013-02-16 20:46:09.278 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 12: 25
2013-02-16 20:46:09.279 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 13: 4
2013-02-16 20:46:09.279 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 14: 1
2013-02-16 20:46:09.280 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 15: 3
2013-02-16 20:46:09.281 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 16: 19
2013-02-16 20:46:09.282 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 17: 5
2013-02-16 20:46:09.283 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 18: 7
2013-02-16 20:46:09.284 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 19: 14
2013-02-16 20:46:09.284 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 20: 247
2013-02-16 20:46:09.285 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 21: 12
2013-02-16 20:46:09.286 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 22: 2
2013-02-16 20:46:09.286 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 23: 5
2013-02-16 20:46:09.287 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 24: 2
2013-02-16 20:46:09.288 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 25: 5
2013-02-16 20:46:09.288 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 26: 239
2013-02-16 20:46:09.289 MyApp[62357:907] (All) Number of items in playlist 27: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the filter only applies to the query’s `items` property, but unfortunately not to the collections’ `items`.

See also this answer:
[Problems with MPMediaQuery and iTunes Match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571663/1534401)