# IOS::How to detect the downloaded songs in MPMediaSongs

Tags: ios, mpmediaquery

I need to implement this functionality.Help me.I don't wan to showing up the downloaded songs in my App.And I'm getting the some songs names like "url format".How to detect that one.Thanks.

```
playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    playlists = [playlistsQuery collections];
    NSArray *playlistsss = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];
    for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlistsss) {
        NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
        NSArray *songs = [playlist items];

        for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {

            NSString *songTitle =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
            NSString *str_artistName =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
            NSLog(@"teh artist name is --->%@",str_artistName);
            playlists=[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
            NSLog(@"the songs titles---->%@",array_playList);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean by "downloaded", the one in the cloud?

Comment: Thanks for replay.Yes,but some songs names getting like "URL Format[http://downloadedsongs/examplewebsite.com/]"how to detect that one.If I click that song App will be crashing.

Comment: help me please I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: For the on in the cloud: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490120/problems-with-mpmediaquery-and-itunes-match/14571663#14571663. For the other ones, I don't know where is "URL Format" exactly in the name.